# speed up iterating over pandas while cleaning data

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a df of over 1,5 mln rows DataFrame to clean data with regular expressions. That is really slow.. How can I speed things up?

- It appears that I have only around 2000 unique rows in this house df, but how do I iterate over the unique values only and then apply the result back to the df? maybe groupby? or save the columns as categorical and iterate over categories?

I do something of this kind:

```py
    splitters = str.maketrans(' ,()/-', '......')
    n=0
    for i in lev1['listing_price']:
        n+=1
        listing_price = i.replace('£', '').replace('\n', '').translate(
            splitters).split('.')
        pw_pcm_list = []
        price_list = []
        for c in listing_price:
            pw_pcm = re.sub('\d', '', c)
            pw_pcm_list.append(pw_pcm)

            price = re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', '', c)

            price_list.append(price)

        price_list = list(filter(lambda a: a != '', price_list))
        price_list = [int(p) for p in price_list]
        price_list = [np.mean(price_list)]
        pw_pcm_list = list(filter(lambda a: a != '', pw_pcm_list))
        list_ = price_list + pw_pcm_list
        if list_[1] == 'pw':
            price_pcm = int(list_[0] / 7 * 30)
        else:
            price_pcm = list_[0]
        lev1.loc[i, 'listing_price'] = price_pcm
        print(n)
```

That is how series look like (left) and desired output (right)

```
£110pw   471.42
£320pcm  320 
£400 pcm 400
£400 pcm 400
£320pcm  320
£110pw   471.42
```

Comment: The code is difficult to understand (for me definitely). Can you post sample data with actual and expected output. If you can provide comments as a column, then there is a high chance you will get a solution faster.

Comment: Avoid `for` loops and builtin python lists wherever possible; instead, perform "vectorized" transformations on entire columns using numpy and pandas methods. Could you post some example data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to speed things up with applying the for loop to the unique values only and then using `map` function.

```
new_value_dict = {}
for i in df['column'].unique():
    #some data manipulations
    new_value = ....
    new_value_dict.update ({i:new_value})

df['column']=df['column'].map({i: new_value_dict})
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map